# jquery set href link on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a tabbed menu that shows content from a different wordpress categories such as Cars, Trucks and Buses. It randomly selects an active tab each time the page is reloaded. At the bottom of the content of the tabbed menu, there is a "View More" button that links to the full category listing of the corresponding selected tab menu.The problem is that whenever I load or reload the page, the View more button doesn't show any link to the categories page of the active tab menu. However, the link shows when I manually click on another tab menu which should not be so. See the code for the tabbed menu below;

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
<?php
$taxonomy = 'browse';
$queried_term = get_query_var($taxonomy);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, 'slug='.$queried_term);
$items = array("1","2","3");
$array_val = $items[array_rand($items)];
if ($terms) {
    $j = 1;
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $termname = $term->name;
        $termslug = $term->slug;
        if($j == $array_val){
?>
<li data-id="<?php echo trim($termslug);?>" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#m-<?php echo trim(str_replace('/','',$termname));?>" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo trim($termname);?></a></li>
<?php 
        } else { 
?>
<li data-id="<?php echo trim($termslug);?>"><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#m-<?php echo trim(str_replace('/','',$termname));?>" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo trim($termname);?></a></li>
<?php 
        }
        $j++;
    } 
}
?>                  
</ul>
```

At the bottom of the content of the tabbed menu, this is the code for the "View More" button that links to the corresponding selected tab menu below;

```
<a href="" class="nymcls">
    <input type="submit" value="View More" class="btnclass">
</a>
```

This is the jquery code that seems to only work whenever I click on the tabbed menu. I want it to assign the corresponding link of the randomly selected tabbed menu whenever the page is loaded also.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#myTab li").click(function() {
        var templateDir = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/';         
        var catname = $(this).data("id");
        var cat = "browse/"
        $('a.nymcls').each(function() {
            ($(this).attr('href', templateDir + cat + catname +'/?top_rate=yes'));  
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need too call the function that updates the links, also on page load. Not only once the user clicks on the them

```
function updateMoreLink( catname ){
    var templateDir = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/'; 

    var cat = "browse/"

    $('a.nymcls').each(function() {
        ($(this).attr('href', templateDir + cat + catname +'/?top_rate=yes'));
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#myTab li").click(function(){
        updateMoreLink($(this).data("id"));
    });

    updateMoreLink( $("#myTab li.active").data("id") );

});
```

Comment: I tried your code and the link is showing now except it is showing undefined in the url of the button. Do I need to rename the updateMoreLink() or use it as it is?

Comment: I updated my answer. As mentioned in the comment you need to know the category_name of the page's first load. With the code provided above, I cannot extract this information

Comment: Thank you very much thus far. But how can I determine the category_name of the page's first load?

Comment: Thank you so much. It works on perfectly on the homepage although it still shows undefined in the category page.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly appears as undefined?

Comment: The "view more" link. On the homepage it shows the correct link to the right category page (https://example.com/browse/music/?top_rate=yes) but on the in other pages the view more link doesn't link to the correct category page instead it shows undefined in place of the selected category (https://example.com/browse/undefined/?top_rate=yes)